# How to allow gradle access through proxy?

Tags: android-studio, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle is not being able to connect to network.
If I do not write any proxy settings in gradle.properties I recieve error:

> Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please
>   configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Even if I manually write all proxy settings in Android Studio settings, or put a mark on "auto-detect proxy settings", I even isntalled prxoycap, still same error(above). Android Studio connection check(button in settings) says that's all good.

If I write all proxy settings in gradle.properites like

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host
systemProp.http.proxyUser=login
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host
systemProp.https.proxyUser=login
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
```

I recieve this error:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.0/gradle-1.0.0.jar'.
>   Received status code 407 from server: authenticationrequired

If I write in gradle.properties user with domain, like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host
systemProp.http.proxyUser=DOMAIN\login
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host
systemProp.https.proxyUser=DOMAIN\login
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
```

then I get this:

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: peer not authenticated

I found somewhere advise to put same settings in SDK Manager(I did, it started update of tools and asked me for credentials. Update was sucessful, but error with gradle still persistent).

I don't know what to do next, because I'm new to Android Studio and have no expierience and knowledge in this proxy-stuff. Please, any help.
Android Studio 2.1.2